# MVC C# Populate nested objects AJAX JSON JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, post, model-view-controller

I'm not able to populate nested objects when I send a Json with AJAX JQuery.

Specifically I can't populate LineItems.

LineItems is a list of different type of object: can be website or campaign, so on my server side I created two classes (website/campaign) that inherit from a generic product class.

The json format is what the client send me via post, so I want to figured out how to bind automatically (or not) my c# objects with the json that I received.

In the controller, the result until now is the Order populated with his own properties, but the branch of LineItems is always a product without values.

Thanks a lot!

**MODELS**

```
public class Order
{
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; }

    public List<LineItems> LineItems { get; set; }
}

public class LineItems
{
    public Product Product = new Product();
}

public class Product
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Website : Product
{
    public WebsiteDetails WebsiteDetails = new WebsiteDetails();
}

public class WebsiteA : Website
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}

public class PaidSearch : Product
{
    public Campaign Campaign = new Campaign();
}

public class Campaign
{
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
}

public class WebsiteDetails
{
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteBusinessName { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost("rec-order")]
public JsonResult Post([FromForm]Order order)
{
    return Json(new { order = order });
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/api/rec-order",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "Partner": "TNT",
        "OrderID": "999888777",
        "LineItems": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Category": "First Category Website",
                "WebsiteDetails": {
                    "TemplateId": "12",
                    "WebsiteBusinessName": "Lorem Ipsum",
                }
            },
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Category": "First Category Campaign",
                "Campaign": {
                    "CampaignName": "Lorem Ipsum",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `LineItems` class need to contain `int  ID`,`string Category` ... properties, not an object.

You can try this to instead of your current Models

```
public class WebsiteDetails
{
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteBusinessName { get; set; }
}

public class Campaign
{
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
}

public class LineItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public WebsiteDetails WebsiteDetails { get; set; }
    public Campaign Campaign { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public string Partner { get; set; }
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @gmaccario Glad to help :)